# How do I solve for x in this equation given numerical values for b and t?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

```
f[x_] := 6 + Tan[b]*x - 16/t^2 * (1 + (Tan^2)[b])* x^2

b=pi/6
t=150
```

I need to find f(200), how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

```
f[b_, t_, x_] := 6 + Tan[b]*x - 16/t^2*(1 + Tan[b]^2)*x^2
f[Pi/6, 150, 200]//N
```

or

```
b=Pi/6;
t=150;
f[x_] := 6 + Tan[b]*x - 16/t^2 * (1 + Tan[b]^2)* x^2;
f[200]//N
```

83.5441

Comment: 6 + 200/Sqrt[3] - 28.4444 (1 + (Tan^2)[\[Pi]/6]).   This is what I get. How do I simplify this to get a numerical value?

Comment: (Tan^2) does not mean the square of the tangent. It's Tan[b]^2. With this correction: f[200] // N gives a numerical answer.

Comment: ok.. I fixed it!